# Laravel 5.3 upgrade - BroadcastServiceProvider error

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I have tried to upgrade `laravel 5.3` from `5.2` and I am getting following error while `php artisan clear-compiled`

> Class App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider contains 1 abstract
>   method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the
>   remaining methods (Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider::register)

However, I had not facing such an issue while upgrade in my local environment.

The `config/broadcasting.php` is as:

```
<?php
return [
    'default' => env('BROADCAST_DRIVER', 'log'),
    'connections' => [
        'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
        ],
        'redis' => [
            'driver' => 'redis',
            'connection' => 'default',
        ],
        'log' => [
            'driver' => 'log',
        ],
    ],
];
```

The `app/Providers/BroadcastServiceProvider.php` is as:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Broadcast;

class BroadcastServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        Broadcast::routes();
        Broadcast::channel('App.User.{userId}', function ($user, $userId) {
            return (int) $user->id === (int) $userId;
        });
    }
}
```

And `.env` is as:

```
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
#BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher
PUSHER_KEY=someKey
PUSHER_SECRET=SomeSecrete
PUSHER_APP_ID=SomeId
```

I tried setting default `broadcasting driver` to `log`, but seems not working.

Any command I am running like: 
`php artisan cache:clear` Or `php artisan config:clear` Or `php artisan view:clear` Or `php artisan clear-compiled`, I am facing the same error.

I also tried using `composer dump-autoload`, it works fine but after that if I run `php artisan clear-compiled` again then also facing the same error.

Please help me.

Comment: Any experts available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed this error by running following `artisan` commands **before** updating the `composer` to `upgrade to laravel 5.3`.

The commands are:

```
php artisan config:clear 
php artisan cache:clear 
php artisan view:clear 
php artisan clear-compiled
```

and then do

```
composer update
```

It will solve the said error while upgrading to `laravel 5.3`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you didn't realy update the framework, because `Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider::register` method is present in 5.2 and not in 5.3
Double check your update

Comment: May be there is problem of cache or something because in my composer.json I have updated "laravel/framework": "5.3.*". Not sure how to fix this.

Comment: @Dev, did you run `composer update`? You may accidentally use `composer install` instead and get no updates.

Comment: Yes I have run composer update, it is updated successfully and then it runs ```php artisan clear-compiled``` automatically and there I get this error. I am pretty sure I used ```composer update```, not ```composer install```.

Comment: @Dev, you can always open your `composer.lock` file (in the problematic installation) and check which exact version composer installed, so there will not be any doubt.

Comment: "name": "laravel/framework",
            "version": "v5.3.29",
            "source": {
                "type": "git",
                "url": "https://github.com/laravel/framework.git",
                "reference": "someid"
            },

Comment: @Dev, and does file with mentioned ServiceProvider class (in `vendor` directory) really contain old `register` method? If not, it is something about caching.  Maybe try to delete contents of `bootstrap/cache`.

Comment: I cannot make this as trial and error as I am working on production environment.